# Cannot assign to .. because it is a group method

Tags: c#

I am using Moq to write test cases and when I try to assign the mock function within the constructor it comes up with the error saying that I cannot assign it because the target method is a group method however there is only one method defined.

I have written an interface etc. as follows:

...

```
public interface IRSPPortal
{
    string GetOrderStatus(OrderInfo OrderNum);
}

public class RSPPortal : IRSPPortal
{

    public RSPPortal(IRSPPortal GetOrderStatusMock)
    {
        this.GetOrderStatus = GetOrderStatusMock; //This line gives the error
    }

    public string GetOrderStatus(OrderInfo OrderNum)
    {
         //stuff done here to access a database
    }
}
```

...

There is only one method GetOrderStatus(OrderInfo OrderNum) so I don't know why it has classified it as a method group. What is the simplest way to overcome this error?

I have tried to use 
this.GetOrderStatus = GetOrderStatusMock.GetOrderStatus;
but that didn't work either.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to replace the method called GetOrderStatus within an instance of a class. The production code calls a database that I want to replace with a Mocked call that returns a fixed value so that I can unit test the calling code. I am basing my code on [link](https://www.jondjones.com/c-sharp-bootcamp/tdd/mocking/a-basic-code-example-using-moq/). The problem that I have is a compile time error in the line shown above. It won't allow the assignment because it says it is a group method, however I only have one method with that name. I am looking for an explanation to the compile error.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Moq works.  If you want to mock IRSPPortal:

```
Mock<IRSPPortal> rspPortalMock = new Mock<IRSPPortal>();

rspPortalMock.Setup(a => a.GetOrderStatus(It.IsAny<OrderInfo>())).Returns(<string you want returned from the mocked method>);
```

Now you have a mock of IRSPPortal that will return whatever string you want from GetOrderStatus.

To use that mocked object just pass in rspPortalMock.Object to whatever class is using IRSPPortal.

Comment: Thanks. I had written the mock part as you had described but hadn't included in my details. Sorry about that. My code when it calls the SUT, it needs to call the object constructor like `var sut = new RSPPortal(GetOrderStatusMock.Object);` and it is the object constructor where I am having the problem.

Comment: Then as Steve commented, you need to explain more as to what you're trying to do with the class.  And if you're instantiating a new RSPPortal in another class instead of injecting it, then you can't mock it.

Comment: Thanks BrianM. I am using Constructor Injection but the compiler is giving me an error in the method reassignment. Is it more common to use property injection and should I use that instead?

Comment: You really need to give more detail in your question as to exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to mock IRSPPortal for another class that you are unit testing?  If so, IRSPPortal needs to be injected into that class as the mocked object.